# Swagger API for MultivaluedMap Jersey? Is it possible?

Tags: java, api, documentation, jersey, swagger

Is it possible to made API documentation by annotations for `MultivaluedMap` param in Jersey using Swagger?

I have a little piece of code like this:

```
/**
 * Method which serves requests of adding {@link StudentGroup} to DB
 * 
 * @param name
 * @param description
 * @return {@link Response}
 * @throws RestServiceException
 */
 @POST
 @Path("/add")
 public Response addStudentGroup(MultivaluedMap<String, String> formParams) throws 
     RestServiceException {
     String name = formParams.getFirst("name");
     String description = formParams.getFirst("description");
     String studentIds = formParams.getFirst("studentIds");

     (...)

}
```

and I want to use `@ApiParam` to generate `JSON` with documentation data using Swagger and Swagger UI.

If I put `@ApiParam` before `MultivaluedMap<String, String>` formParams it doesn't work. Swagger can not list any params.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like this is a bug in Swagger - I also get this behavior. Using other generic classes with two type parameters (like @ApiParam() HashMap) works fine. Probably it throws the parser off.

I opened [an issue for this](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/issues/172) on the [Swagger bug tracking system](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/issues).

You can also ask them [on their Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/swagger-swaggersocket) or find them on IRC at Freenode#swagger.

Comment: The ticket has been closed since 2013 as "not supported," which is a big problem for properly documenting flexible REST endpoints such as search methods.  :(

Answer (score 2):

I could solve this issue like this. We can make use of @APIImplicitParams annoatation provided by the Swagger API to list all the form elements of the MultiValueMap and use @APIignore on the MultiValueMap itself. Try if something on the lines of the code below works. Good luck. :)

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Create a new 'Student' object")
@ApiImplicitParams({
      @ApiImplicitParam(name = "X-ClientId", value = "X-ClientId", required = true, dataType = "String", paramType = "header"),
      @ApiImplicitParam(name = "id", value = "Enter an ID for the student.", dataTypeClass = String.class, paramType = "query"),
      @ApiImplicitParam(name = "name", value = "Enter a Name for the Student.", dataTypeClass = String.class, paramType = "query")
  })
  ResponseEntity addStudent(
      @NotBlank @RequestHeader(value = X_CLIENTID) String headerXclient,
      @ApiIgnore @RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> requestParams) {
          StudentRequest request = new StudentRequest(requestParams);

          (... Your Code Implementation ...)
      };
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently not supported, but as Eyal said, there's a ticket open in github issues and it may be fairly easy to implement.